# A question on logic and some functional inequalities

Tags: functions, inequality, functional-inequalities

Suppose that I have a (generic) function $g$ and arguments $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$. I know that $g$ satisfies the inequalities

$$1 < \frac{g(b)}{b} < \frac{g(a)}{a} < 2.$$

I also know that the following implications are true:

> > $$g(a) < g(b) \Longrightarrow \left\{a < b \Longleftrightarrow \frac{g(a)}{b} < \frac{g(b)}{a}\right\},$$

and

> > $$b < a \Longrightarrow \left\{g(b) < g(a) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{g(b)}{a} < \frac{g(a)}{b}\right\}.$$

Does it follow that

> > $$a < b \Longleftrightarrow g(a) < g(b) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{g(a)}{b} < \frac{g(b)}{a}?$$

(Note that I don't have information about whether $g$ is injective or not.)

Comment: How should I interpret the brackets? For example does $$g(a) < g(b) \Longrightarrow \{a < b \Longleftrightarrow \frac{g(a)}{b} < \frac{g(b)}{a}\}$$ mean "If $g(a) < g(b)$, then $a < b$ which is equivalent to $\frac{g(a)}{b} < \frac{g(b)}{a}$"? or does it just say, if the condition $g(a) < g(b)$ is true, the statement in the brackets is true?

Comment: Are only the implications as a whole true? or the statements in the brackets too? Because we can easily find a counterexample when $g(a)>g(b)$, but $a<b$ (an inverse function for example), because the left side of both implications will be false, hence we do not care about the brackets, as the implication with false on the left side is always true.

Comment: For example $g(x)=\frac{5,5}{\sqrt{x}}$ with $a=2$, $b=3$, would fulfill your requirements, but contradict your conjecture.

Comment: @GEO, as to your first question:  If the condition $g(a) < g(b)$ is true, then the statement (i.e., the biconditional) in the brackets is true.

Comment: @GEO, as to your second question:  Yes, only the implications as a whole are true.  If the hypothesis in each implication is true, then the conclusion (which is a biconditional) would also be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We try to find a counterexample for your implication, by assuming $ a<b $ and $ g(a)>g(b)$.
Both of this conditions render the two implications you gave as true, because both conditions on the left of your implications are false, hence the implications are true by definition.

Now our assumptions fit a proportional function like for example $g(x)=\frac{k}{x}$. With a little bit of trying to match your inequality chain from the beginning we get for example:

$$a=2;\quad b=3; \qquad g(x)=\frac{10}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

This fits all your requirements, but shows your implication that $a < b \Longleftrightarrow g(a) < g(b)$ is not true.

Hence, the answer to your question "Does it follow that ..." is "No".

Comment: Before I accept your answer @GEO, can you comment on which part of the biconditional

$$a < b \Longleftrightarrow g(a) < g(b)$$

is the implication not true?  I am guessing it is:

$$a < b \Longrightarrow g(a) < g(b).$$

Comment: Right, because the left condition is true and right one wrong. The implication from right to left is true in our specific example.